# Protect device from losing power when to much current is drawn

Tags: raspberry-pi, amperage, motor-controller, nimh

I use an EVX 3014 RC ESC (BEC provides 5V & 1.5amps) and I'm worried that to much of the current will be drawn to the motors that not enough of it will be available to the raspberry pi computer (Rev 1 Model B) on board the car. Will the ESC provide enough power through the BEC to the pi at all speeds, if not how can I give the pi a secure power supply?

[EVX 3014](http://notices.patrickmodelisme.com/telecharger/Traxxas/Traxxas_EVX_ESC_Manual.pdf)

[raspberry-pi b rev1](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/category/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-model-b)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please provide hyperlinks to datasheets for any devices you mention. Put them **in the question** rather than in the comments.

Comment: roughly, you have to guarantee that the internal resistance of the battery is low enough and that you have enough bulk capacitance to minimize power supply sags. 1.5A isnt that much though, it should only be a problem with a poor battery and too little capacitance on the rail.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want to hear, I think, but the way to do it is to provide 2 power supplies - one for the pi, one for the motors. The pi supply will not need to provide much current, so it can be smaller and cheaper than the motor supply.

As a bonus, should you decide to upgrade to more power motors which require a different voltage, you're already set for the pi.

Comment: This is a very shit answer, I am very unhappy now. People will no longer answer my question now that it has already been "answered." If I used an independent power supply for the pi I would have to charge them independently and when one battery runs out presumably the one powering the pi it would disable the functionality of the car. If I did have a good battery for the pi it would have to be expensive an it would increase weight. If I had two I would also have to monitor the capacity further complicating things. Your bonus is completely negated by the fact that if I got more powerful motors I

Comment: Would also have to upgrade the ESC which would already have a BEC integrated within it that could power the pi. The problem is not that the ESC cannot power the pi, the problem is when there is a sudden power drop when braking and accelerating to top speed. Delete your answer so someone else will answer 

Comment: @1971chevycamaro - " I am very unhappy now. People will no longer answer my question now that it has already been "answered." " Not if they disagree with my answer. You have no idea how this site works. First responder does not take control. Chill. Calm down. Relax. Take deep breaths. If no one else answers, it's because either they think my answer is a good one, or because they don't find the question interesting. In neither case have I ruined the question for you. Chill out.

Comment: I've seen many interesting questions on this stackexchange site and on the ones that have inappropriate answers the questions gain no new activity. I think people have no interest in viewing something that they see has already been answered, unless it pertains to them in which case they would want the answer but be unable to answer because they wouldn't know it themselves.